# fashion_mnist tensor flow model doesn't work correctly after converting to tensorflow lite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, mnist

Tensor flow keras model returns incorrect values after converting to tensor flow lite.

I am trying to create tensor flow model to run on Android device.
First I decided to test it on sample fashion_mnist.
Everything worked correctly with standard keras model (expected results were correct for my sample images).
But as soon as I converted it to tflite model it.. (and used Interpreter to predict answer) it returns the same answer for all the images.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

print(tf.__version__)

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']


def prepare_keras_model():
    fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),  ## warstwa neuronow
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)  # bo 10 rodzajow ubran
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)  # increaase to 10 after tests
    # test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
    # print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
    return tf.keras.Sequential([model, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])


def calculate_prediction(model, test_data, index):
    predictions = model.predict(test_data)
    value = predictions[index][np.argmax(predictions[index])]
    print("PRED RESULTS " + str(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[index])]) + " VALUE " + str(value))
    plt.imshow(test_data[index], cmap=plt.cm.binary)


def load_image_from_disk(img_name):
    test_data = []
    test_path = "."
    IMG_SIZE = 28

    test_img = os.path.join(test_path, img_name + ".png")
    img_array = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.imread(test_img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))  # loading the image
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize the image
    float_array = (new_array / 255.0).astype(np.float32)
    return float_array


def convert_keras_to_tflite(model):
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    return tflite_model


def save_model_to_file(model, file_name):
    with open(file_name + '.tflite', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(model)


def load_model_from_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name + '.tflite', 'rb') as f:
        byte_data = f.read()
    return byte_data


def run_tflite_pred(model, image):
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=model)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
    output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]

    interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, [image])
    interpreter.invoke()
    result = interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
    best_index = np.argmax(result)
    print("test " + class_names[best_index] + " " + str(result[0][best_index]))


# -------------- START --------------

# probability_model = prepare_keras_model()
# tflite_model = convert_keras_to_tflite(probability_model)

tflite_model = load_model_from_file("2")

# calculate_prediction(probability_model, test_images, 1)

image = load_image_from_disk("shoe")
plt.imshow(image)
run_tflite_pred(tflite_model, image)

# save_model_to_file(tflite_model, "2")
```